# Match multiple lines that do NOT start with "<p>" without using the "m" modifier (golang flavor)

Tags: regex, regex-group, modifier

I'm trying to match multiple lines that do not begin with a HTML `<p>` tag, using just the `g` modifier with the Golang flavor of RegEx.

Here's an example:

```
Lorem ipsum

<p><span class="slugline">INNEN. Wohnung, Erdgeschoss – Tag</span></p><br>

Dolor sit amet

1234

<p><span class="slugline">INNEN. Wieslers Wohnung, Fahrstuhl – Tag</span></p><br>

Et respice finem

<p><span class="slugline">AUSSEN. Wohnung - Nacht</span></p><br>

<p><span class="slugline">INNEN. Wohnung, Erdgeschoss – Tag</span></p><br>

<p><span class="charleft">Maik</span><span class="dialogleft">(leise) Hallo.</span></p>

Quod erat demonstrandum
```

The regex should match the lines and paragraphs that begin with:

- Lorem ipsum
- Dolor sit amet
- 1234
- Et respice finem
- Quod erat demonstrandum

It's easy with the `mg` modifiers of the Golang flavor: [`^([^<\n\r]|<([^p]|$)).*`](https://regex101.com/r/yyxGPR/1)

But I'm looking for a regular expression that works without the `m` modifier. I can't make it work with just the `g` modifier.

Comment: Can you show us the code you've written?

Comment: Your initial phrase contradicts the title. You want or don't want `m`? (Also, explain why)

Comment: This should work: `(^|\n)[^<\n][^p][^>].*`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of matching what you want to keep, you could match what you don't want, and use that as pattern to *split* the string.

If your text sits in variable `s`, you could continue like this:

```
    para := regexp.MustCompile("[\n\r]+(<p>.*[\n\r]*)*")
    lines := para.Split(s, -1)
    for _, line := range lines {
        fmt.Println(line)
    }
```

This will then output:

```
Lorem ipsum
Dolor sit amet
1234
Et respice finem
Quod erat demonstrandum
```